# Extended Valid Elements in TinyMCE with directives

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, tinymce-4

I wanna declare `:options` as a Valid Element

```
extended_valid_elements: 'swiper[:options]'
```

but that brings an error while

```
extended_valid_elements: 'swiper[options]'
```

works, but I wanna use `:options` since I need it as a Vue Directive

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a defect in how TinyMCE processes attributes.  My guess is its due to the fact that `:` has special meaning in defining attributes and using `:` as the first character is not properly handled.

I would open an issue on the TinyMCE Issue Tracker:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues